# How can I get the handle of a toolbar button?

Tags: winapi

I want to get the handle of a toolbar button. I know its ID and the window handle the toolbar button is in. But the GetDlgItem function doesn't seem to work for toolbar buttons.

```
 GetDlgItem(windowHandle, buttonID);
```

I thought maybe the function SendMessage() with the right parameters could get the handle, but I didn't find any msg parameter that would help for the same.

What is a function that can help me get its handle?

Answer (score 1):

Toolbar's buttons don't have handles (they are not windows, as regular buttons are). There are lots of toolbar messages (TB_*) to work with those buttons.

Refer [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760435(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760435%28VS.85%29.aspx)

You can send TB_BUTTONCOUNT message to get button count in toolbar and create a simple loop which goes through each button and checks if disbled by sending TB_ISBUTTONENABLED. You can also send TB_GETBUTTON message to get more information about each button in TBBUTTON

Comment: You can send those messages, but it requires `WriteProcessMemory` and `ReadProcessMemory`. They are not marshalled cross process unless I am very much mistaken.

Comment: I see. So what msgs or other function could I use to click the toolbar button in program 2?

Comment: You do it the way I already said. You use UI Automation. We keep telling you that. At some point you'll believe us!!

Comment: Thereee has to be a function dude.... SendMessage().... with a message out of all the ones out there. I mean I found the TB_PRESSBUTTON message but even when I press the button, the window doesn't appear. I am super close lol. Yeah I respect the fact that UI Automation must be awesome, but if there is a function out there for my purposes it would be much more convenient to try to find it than jump into a new library

Comment: @user3552287 OK, do it you way if you prefer. Obviously I cannot force you to do it another way.

Comment: @user3552287: as you already mentioned, you can use the `TB_PRESSBUTTON` message. Send `TB_PRESSBUTTON` to the Toolbar HWND with `wParam` set to the button ID and `lParam` set to `MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0)`, then send it again with `lParam` set to `MAKELPARAM(FALSE, 0)`. Alternatively, try sending [BN_CLICKED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825.aspx) and [`NM_CLICK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760490.aspx) notification messages to the Toolbar's parent HWND.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you keep pushing people to use UIAutomation. That may be the *preferred* way to manipulate external processes, but it is by no means the *easiest* way, and most people have never heard of UIAutomation or know how to use it.

Comment: @Remy How are you going to push a toolbar button in another process more easily than UI automation? Also, good luck with that `TB_GETBUTTON` message to another process. You can do that way if you prefer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: then why don't you show examples of using UIAutomation and `TB_GETBUTTON`/`TB__PUSHBUTTON` to push a toolbar button, and let's compare them.

Comment: @Remy in a question that asks how to get the window handle of a toolbar button? You realise that your easy solution involves VirtualAlloc and ReadProcessMemory etc.

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar buttons are non-windowed. There is no window handle for you to retrieve.

If you wish to automate toolbar buttons then you should use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684076.aspx).

Comment: Oh ok, so how would I then click on a specific toolbar button? I mean I thought of using SendMessage(windowHandle, Msg, blah, blah)... but I couldn't find an appropriate Msg and other parameters to do the job. BN_CLICK doesn't seem to work since it need the handle to the button, and that's why i asked for a handle for the toolbar button :P

Comment: That's a different question. I would suggest that you use UI Automation.

Answer (score 0):

You can. Two ways:

1: Create the button yourself

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK myModelessToolbar(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            HWND hYellowButton =
              CreateWindow(L"BUTTON",
                           L"Yellow button",
                           BS_ICON | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                           610, 0, 20, 20, hDlg, (HMENU)1, NULL, NULL);

            m_pBitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(L"Yellow.jpg"); // Image must be in executable directory.
            m_pBitmap->GetHICON(&hicon);
            LRESULT lr = SendMessage(hYellowButton, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_ICON, (LPARAM)hicon);

            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

2: Using the Visual Studio editor, set the button to receive bitmaps. This worked for me as well. Put this in the wm_initdialog section as well.

```
HWND test = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_BUTTON8);
lr = SendMessage(test, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_ICON, (LPARAM)hicon);
```